# Image registration b-spline opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagej

Here is my question:
My optical system is made of a camera plus a circular plexiglass "lens" that changes its curvature depending on pressure (radial bending).

This curvature induces a deformation of the image captured by the camera.
To correct this deformation, images need to be calibrated.
Calibration can be made with a grid (chessboard, dots, lines), pressure range has to be discretized with a certain step.
For each pressure step, an image of the grid has to be taken.
Then each image has to be compared to the reference one (P=0), and a transformation matrix has to be computed and stored.
Finally, each image taken during the experiment for a specific pressure has to be corrected by the transformation matrix.

The deformation is non-linear (not only a combination of rotations and translations), but most likely Barrel distortion. (again not induced by the camera)
Which looks like that:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29#mediaviewer/File:Barrel_distortion.svg](http://barrel%20deformation)

I found a plugin in ImageJ called BunwarpJ, http://biocomp.cnb.csic.es/~iarganda/bUnwarpJ/

and I basically want to know if there is an equivalent way to produce the same result in Opencv. 
(CalibrateCamera won't do the trick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCv has an [`undistort` function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort) that can take a current image, a matrix of camera coefficients, distorsion coeffs. and produces a new image corrected for sent camera coeffs. and a new set of camera coeffs. (if you need to do other transformations on the new image).

I have not used it before, so I can't say what exactly are camera or distorsion coefficients are but as manual describes:

> The function transforms an image to compensate radial and tangential
>   lens distortion. The function is simply a combination of
>   initUndistortRectifyMap() (with unity R ) and remap() (with bilinear
>   interpolation).

So checking those two funcs. out are a good way to find out.

I believe you misunderstood the manual perhaps because you seem to think that [CalibrateCamera](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) does this for you. Instead [CalibrateCamera](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) actually returns the camera and distorsion coeffs. which you need to `undistort` your image.

Each lens has its own **constant** coeffs. which in your case means that you'll have to `calibrateCamera` for a range of pressures (I assume you control that experimentally?) and then call different `undistort` func. with different parameters which you'll get out of your experiments.

Comment: thank you @ljetibo for your answer, I understood perfectly how cameracalibrate and undistort work. but in terms of time, it's a huge investment (taking several images for each pressure step), since I already have an alternative solution (bUnwarp) on imageJ which works as pixel based registration approach (combined with feature based approach), I will be using it.

Comment: @MugenOp It's sometimes hard to guess the knowledge of OP especially when user is still new. Sorry if that made you uncomfortable. Programing in computer vision usually does take a lot of time, and can be very hard. But if you want results to **exactly** behave by your rules is still the only option to go. However I'd probably also use BUnwrapJ. ImageJ is open source and has an [API](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/jython/index.html), it might perhaps pay off to dig around there to gain access to the unwrap functionality?

Answer (score 0):

A matrix can only capture a linear transformation (or possibly a linear transformation in homogeneous space), not a general distortion.

In my experience any attempt to use a single global transformation formula wouldn't be very accurate (it's not trivial to get just 99.9% accuracy). Even just correcting camera lens distortion this way is difficult if you want high accuracy.

In the past I got good enough results using a sparse global RBF interpolation, but later I moved to an interpolating 2d spline approach; if you can choose your calibration points to be on a regular grid this is the solution I would suggest.

In the end the mapping could be a 2-valued 3d interpolating spline on a regular grid (XY for the image, Z for the pressure; values UV are the pixel coordinates).

Straightening the image once pressure is known is just texture mapping.